# Port monitoring using nagios

Tags: nagios

I want to monitor a ruby program using nagios3.3.1 . I have nagios installed on Centos5.7 and the the ruby program is in windows server 2012 r2 64 bit.
 I just tried it by opening a port 4546 using ruby program and monitor that port using check_tcp plugin. 
Below is my service definition.

```
define service {
use  local-service

host_name  winserver-2012

service_description  monitor ruby

check_command  check_tcp!4546

}
```

But the result is "CRITICAL-Socket timeout after 10 seconds"..

What should I do for monitoring a ruby program? Is it possible to monitor a port which is just opened.?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have anything to do with ruby, check_tcp doesn't care who is listening on the port, as long as there is actually something that's listening. Try `telnet winserver-2012 4546` to check if the port is reachable. If it isn't, it's most likely your windows firewall is blocking incoming connections, or your ruby program binds to the port but doesn't listen on it. Try `netstat -an | findstr "4546"` on the windows machine to see if your ruby program actually listens for connections.

Comment: I checked that port, there is no service started on that port. Its just opened and not listening any connections. I tried  "check_command    telnet winserver-2012 4546" in service definition. But on verification it gives me error. It is saying "the service telnet is not specified any where"

Comment: The telnet command was intended from the command line, not in nagios, just to see if it can connect. But if your ruby program does not listen on the port, you can't monitor it with check_tcp. The only thing you could do is install something like nsclientpp and use it to check if the process is running.

Comment: nsclientpp is already installed. Which is the plugin for monitoring windows processes? How to use it?